# Morphia query to filter and fetch an embedded list element

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am new to NoSQL and morphia. I am using Morphia to query MongoDB.

I have a sample collection as below:

```
[
    {
        "serviceId": "id1",
        "serviceName": "ding",
        "serviceVersion": "1.0",
        "files": [
            {
                "fileName": "b.html",
                "fileContents": "contentsA"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "b.html",
                "fileContents": "contentsB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serviceId": "id2",
        "serviceName": "ding",
        "serviceVersion": "2.0",
        "files": [
            {
                "fileName": "b.html",
                "fileContents": "contentsA"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "b.html",
                "fileContents": "contentsB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to fetch an element in "files" List , given service name, service version and filename., using Morphia.

I was able to get what I want using the query below:

```
db.ApiDoc.find({ serviceName: "ding", serviceVersion: "2.0"}, { files: { $elemMatch: { fileName: "b.html" } } }).sort({ "_id": 1}).skip(0).limit(30);
```

What I tried so far :

I tried using "elemmatch" api that morphia has, but no luck.

```
query =  ...createQuery(
                    Result.class);
query.and(query.criteria("serviceName").equal("ding"),
                    query.criteria("serviceVersion").equal(
                            "2.0"));
query.filter("files elem",BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("fileName", "a.html").get());
```

I seem to get the entire Result collection with all the files. I would like to get only the matched files(by filename).

can some one help me how I can get this to work?

Thanks
rajesh

Comment: Can you possibly add the `.field("files.filename").eq("a.html")` to the query conditions and then use `.retrievedFields("files.$.filename").get()` to get a positional operator match on the query selection instead of the `$eleMatch` projection form? The only real difference is without the query portion `$elemMatch` projection would return empty arrays if the condition there was not met. The positional operator should return the first match in just the same way but of course only for documents that match the condition. Not in a position to test myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to get just the matching sub element. You can request just to have the 'files' array returned but all elements will be included in the result set and you will have to refilter in your code.

The other option is to make Files a collection of its own with a serviceId field and then you'll have more power to load only certain files.

Comment: I was able to do this with a mongo query using $elemmatch, not sure why this doesn't work using morphia, is this a limitation?  I am open to making changes to the collection structure, will you be able to provide an example on how i can make this to work with changes?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that.
the filter doesn't really work like projection.

try this :

```
datastore.createQuery(Result.class)
.field("serviceName").equal("dong")
.field("serviceVersion").equal("2.0")
.field("files.filename").equal("a.html")
.project("files.$.filename", true);
```